# Why won't my shell script work?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm using bash and this is my code

```
for i in $(seq 20)
do 
     if [ $i % 3 == 0 ]
     then 
            echo HI
     else 
            echo $i
     fi
done
```

So the output should be:
1
2
hi
4
5
hi
...
and so on.
But I keep getting this error when I run my shell.
script.sh 4: [: 1: unexpected operator
1
then it just goes on like that until 20.
I've tried different things but i can't get it to work.

Comment: If i use   if [[ $((i % 3)) == 0 ]] it makes the same output just with a [[:

Comment: it says i'm using bash and at the beginning of the script I do have #!/bin/bash

Comment: Are you sure you're using Bash?  If so, which version?  (`sh --version` and `bash --version`).  My suspicion is that you're using something other than Bash — maybe `/bin/sh` is actually `dash` instead?  When you run the script, do you run `sh script.sh` or `bash script.sh` or `./script.sh` or something else?  Is there a blank line at the top of the file or anything odd like that?

Comment: yeah i wasn't running as a bash. figured it out thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the line containing the `if` to:

```
 if [[ $((i%3)) == 0 ]]
```

That will work.

Comment: I still get this as the output though "script.sh: 4: script.sh: [[: not found 1" and then all the way to "script.sh: 4: fizzbuzz.sh: [[: not found 20"

Comment: @Matt.Doe: You say you're using Bash, but how are you running `script.sh`?  Is it as `sh script.sh`?  Or what do you have in the shebang line — is it `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`?  I suspect you're using `sh` rather than `bash` — which is why this wouldn't work.

Comment: how would I use bash. I have been using sh script.sh and up top of the script i have #!/bin/bash. This is my first script by the way.

Comment: omg i feel so stupid. I was running it as sh script.sh when I had to run it as bash script.sh. Then I got the right output. thanks so much

Comment: I tested that it works as you expected, could you please check it again, notice the place of space character

Answer (score 3):

Even a bit simpler:

```
if ((i%3 == 0)) # No '$' needed
then
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
for i in {1..20}
do 
     if [ `expr $i % 3` == 0 ]
     then 
            echo HI
     else 
            echo $i
     fi
done
```

Comment: you can also use `-eq` instead of `==`

Comment: The only thing in this that might cause trouble is `==` instead of `=`, but if you're running Bash, it should work correctly.  Using `expr` is a heavy-weight solution, but not invalid.  I'd prefer to see `$(expr $i % 3)`, too.  You do have to be careful with all the spaces, of course.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like below mentioned format,

if [ $i%3 == 0 ];
then

but if you introduce "==" symbol it will only produce incremental value from 1 to 20.